# Is equivalence of a CFG and an RG undecidable?

Tags: computability, formal-grammars, decision-problem

I know that the equivalence of two context-free grammars is undecidable, but what about the equivalence of a regular grammar and a context-free grammar?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

It is undecidable whether for a given CFG $G$, $L(G)=\Delta^*$, the set of all strings (over the terminal alphabet of $G$). That answers your question, by chosing the most simple regular grammar.

Comment: I thought the most simple regular *language*  was the empty one. ;)

Comment: Ah, that's excellent. Thanks, Hendrik!

Comment: @babou Indeed. You made me smile. Nevertheless the concept "empty language" might be very confusing to some. In a recent exam some students noted that $\{a,b,c,d\}$ had $17$ subsets: $2^4$ usual ones, plus the empty set.